# Help with exponential sum equality

Tags: complex-analysis

I am in the middle of a demonstration and I wanted to make sure I got it right:

so let $S(\alpha)= \sum_{n=M+1}^{M+N} a_n e(n \alpha)$, where $\{ a_n \}_n \cup \mathbb{C}, M,N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $e(\alpha)=e^{2\pi i \alpha}$. If $\alpha_1 ,..., \alpha_R \in \mathbb{R}$ then 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=1}^R | S(\alpha_r + \beta)|^2 &= \sum_r \left( \sum_{n=M+1}^{M+N} a_n e(n(\alpha_r+\beta)) \sum_{k=M+1}^{M+N} \overline{a_k} e(-k(\alpha_r+\beta)) \right) \\
&= \sum_r \left( \sum_{n=M+1}^{M+N} a_n \sum_{k=M+1}^{M+N} \overline{a_k} e((n-k)(\alpha_r+\beta))  \right),
\end{align*}

My doubt is here: can I say that $e((n-k)(\alpha_r+\beta)) = 1$ since $n-k$ is an integer? If so, I can then continue and say that the sum is equal to

$$\sum_r \sum_n |a_n|^2 = R \sum_n |a_n|^2.$$

Thank you very much in advance for your help :)